# mySQL delete row with count(*) GROUP and HAVING

Tags: mysql, sql, count, sql-delete, having-clause

I have this query where i get all double entries with the same articleID and the categoryID = 2153
Now i want to delete this rows. But this seems not to work directly.
So i tried it with subquery, but when i use IN i would need a subquery which returns only the id. But that's also not possible.

How can i delete the rows from this query?

```
SELECT id, articleID, categoryID, count(*) AS count 
FROM `s_articles_categories`
GROUP BY articleID
HAVING count(*) > 1 AND categoryID = 2153
```

Comment: Do you want to delete all duplicated records, or keep one in each group of duplicates ?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the id is the primary key for the table s_articles_categories   You could use a join on the subselect result.

To delete all rows :

```
delete  r.* 
from s_articles_categories r
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT id, articleID, categoryID, count(*) AS count FROM
    `s_articles_categories` r
    GROUP BY articleID
   HAVING count(*) > 1 AND categoryID = 2153

) t on t.id = r.id
```

Comment: @GMB   .. thanks for editing  .. (i have some problems of dysgraphia that when I write in English are accentuated)  .. many thansk  .. upvoted

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete all duplicates but keep one of them in each group, then you can use the following query :

```
DELETE FROM `s_articles_categories` s
WHERE s.categoryID = 2153 AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM `s_articles_categories` s1
    WHERE s1.articleID = s.articleID AND s1.categoryID = s.categoryID AND s1.id < s.id
)
```

Comment: Thank you. But i need to delete only the duplicates where the category is 2153

Comment: @user3586022 : query updated. But still, you would need to tell use if you want to delete *all* duplicates (answer by @scaisEdge) or keep one in each group (my answer).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend writing this  as:

```
delete ac
    from s_articles_categories ac join
         (select articleId, categoryid, min(id) as min_id
          from s_articles_categories
          where categoryID = 2153
          group by articleId, categoryid
         ) ac2
         on ac2.articleId = ac.articleId and
            ac2.categoryid = ac.categoryid and
            ac.id > ac2.min_id
```